Problem with generics types and kotlin shadowing java function
I'm trying to use the indriya java lib for unit conversion in a Kotlin Multiplatform Lib project. I have the following issue:
import tech.units.indriya.format.SimpleUnitFormat
import tech.units.indriya.quantity.Quantities
import javax.measure.format.UnitFormat

class AndroidPlatform : Platform {
    override val name: String = "Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}"
    private val unitFormat: UnitFormat = SimpleUnitFormat.getInstance()

    override fun convert(value: Double, sourceUnit: String, targetUnit: String): Double {

        val fromUnit: javax.measure.Unit<*> = unitFormat.parse(sourceUnit)
        val fromQuantity = Quantities.getQuantity(value, fromUnit)
        val toUnit = unitFormat.parse(targetUnit)

        val result = fromQuantity.to()

        return result.value.toDouble()
    }
}

actual fun getPlatform(): Platform = AndroidPlatform()

The issue is in fromQuantity.to(). If I click on to I see this:
  /**
   * @see Quantity#to(Unit)
   */
  ComparableQuantity<Q> to(Unit<Q> unit);

But once I pass toUnit as param that "to" leads to the kotlin extension function "to", which I don't want ofc. The problem seems to be because some types are only known at runtime.
Unit<?> parse(CharSequence csq) throws MeasurementParseException;

How to be able to convert then?

What does the compiler say if you do val result: ComparableQuantity<*> = fromQuantity.to()?

The same @k314159

If you're writing this specifically for Android, you might also want to check if android.icu.util.MeasureUnit is easier to use.

Also, if you prefer to have just one multiplatform implementation for all of your platforms, you might want to consider https://github.com/vsirotin/si-units

The reason for the failure to compile is that, in the following line:
   val result = fromQuantity.to(toUnit)

the to function is defined only for types that have the same generic parameter. But in your case, fromQuantity is of type ComparableQuantity<*> and toUnit is of type Unit<*> and the compiler cannot see that the two *s are the same generic type.
To fix this, you need to tell the compiler that they are indeed the same generic type, preferably by making your function generic:
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <Q: Quantity<Q>> convert(value: Double, sourceUnit: String, targetUnit: String): Double {

        val fromUnit = unitFormat.parse(sourceUnit) as javax.measure.Unit<Q>
        val fromQuantity = Quantities.getQuantity(value, fromUnit)
        val toUnit = unitFormat.parse(targetUnit) as javax.measure.Unit<Q>

        val result = fromQuantity.to(toUnit)

        return result.value.toDouble()
    }


I'm amazed, this made my day, I learned something today, thanks!

This answer is incorrect. "Kotlin is more strict with its type system" - assuming one is to read '... in comparison with java' there (and what else is it 'more strict' than?) - not so. Transpile this to java and it wouldn't accept it either. The simple notion that one ? is not the same as another ? (in kotlinese, that'd be *) is obvious, inherent to generics, and indeed applied both by java and by kotlin.

@rzwitserloot you're right, Java is just as strict and also requires the generic types to be the same. I've therefore removed that statement from my answer. I hope the rest of it is ok.
